# APEX_JSON get array object

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex-5.1

```
declare
       l_json_doc VARCHAR2(32767); 
       l_numcols number;
       l_numrows number;      
begin

l_json_doc := '{
    "table": {
        "name": "sometablename",
        "numofcolumns": 5,
        "numofrows": 5,
        "colheadings": [{
                "colname": "customcol1",
                "coltype": "number"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol2",
                "coltype": "varchar2"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol3",
                "coltype": "varchar2"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol4",
                "coltype": "varchar2"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol5",
                "coltype": "number"
            }
        ],
        "data": [{
                "customcol1": "datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "datacolumn5"
            },
            {
                "customcol1": "2datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "2datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "2datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "2datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "2datacolumn5"
            },
            {
                "customcol1": "3datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "3datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "3datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "3datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "3datacolumn5"
            },
            {
                "customcol1": "4datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "4datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "4datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "4datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "4datacolumn5"
            }
        ]
    }
}';

APEX_JSON.parse(l_json_doc);

l_numcols := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'table.colheadings');

l_numrows := APEX_JSON.get_count(p_path => 'table.data');

FOR i IN 1 .. l_numrows LOOP
FOR j IN 1 .. l_numcols LOOP

dbms_output.put_line('TEST ' || APEX_JSON.get_varchar2(p_path => 'table.data[%d]')  ); 

END LOOP;
END LOOP;


end;
```

This is my code which is supposed to extract the data array objects. I expect the following output:

```
TEST {"customcol1": "datacolumn1","customcol2": "datacolumn2","customcol3": "datacolumn3","customcol4": "datacolumn4","customcol5": "datacolumn5"}

TEST { "customcol1": "2datacolumn1","customcol2": "2datacolumn2","customcol3": "2datacolumn3","customcol4": "2datacolumn4","customcol5": "2datacolumn5"}
```

etc ...

But when I try to get the json object from the data array using the APEX_JSON.get_varchar2 it returns empty

Answer (score 1):

Two problems with the code there

- You have not provided an index to the `get_varchar2` function. So the path is not complete. You need to provide a value in the `p0` parameter of that function
- That's not how `APEX_JSON.get_varchar2` works. You are expecting the
  function to return the entire JSON object in the data array but `get_varchar2` cannot do that. It can only get you the **VALUE** that is a VARCHAR at a specified path. It cannot get you the entire object.

For your output

```
DECLARE
   l_json_doc   VARCHAR2 (32767);
   l_numcols    NUMBER;
   l_numrows    NUMBER;
   v_colname    VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
   l_json_doc := '{
    "table": {
        "name": "sometablename",
        "numofcolumns": 5,
        "numofrows": 5,
        "colheadings": [{
                "colname": "customcol1",
                "coltype": "number"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol2",
                "coltype": "varchar2"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol3",
                "coltype": "varchar2"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol4",
                "coltype": "varchar2"
            },
            {
                "colname": "customcol5",
                "coltype": "number"
            }
        ],
        "data": [{
                "customcol1": "datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "datacolumn5"
            },
            {
                "customcol1": "2datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "2datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "2datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "2datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "2datacolumn5"
            },
            {
                "customcol1": "3datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "3datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "3datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "3datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "3datacolumn5"
            },
            {
                "customcol1": "4datacolumn1",
                "customcol2": "4datacolumn2",
                "customcol3": "4datacolumn3",
                "customcol4": "4datacolumn4",
                "customcol5": "4datacolumn5"
            }
        ]
    }
}';

   APEX_JSON.parse (l_json_doc);

   l_numcols := APEX_JSON.get_count (p_path => 'table.colheadings');

   l_numrows := APEX_JSON.get_count (p_path => 'table.data');

   FOR i IN 1 .. l_numrows
   LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put ('TEST {');

      FOR j IN 1 .. l_numcols
      LOOP
         v_colname :=
            apex_json.get_varchar2 ('table.colheadings[%d].colname', j);
         DBMS_OUTPUT.put (
            '"' || v_colname || '":"'
            || APEX_JSON.get_varchar2 (
                  p_path   => 'table.data[%d].' || v_colname,
                  p0       => i)
            || '",');
      END LOOP;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('}');
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Here is the output of the code:

```
TEST {"customcol1":"datacolumn1","customcol2":"datacolumn2","customcol3":"datacolumn3","customcol4":"datacolumn4","customcol5":"datacolumn5",}
TEST {"customcol1":"2datacolumn1","customcol2":"2datacolumn2","customcol3":"2datacolumn3","customcol4":"2datacolumn4","customcol5":"2datacolumn5",}
TEST {"customcol1":"3datacolumn1","customcol2":"3datacolumn2","customcol3":"3datacolumn3","customcol4":"3datacolumn4","customcol5":"3datacolumn5",}
TEST {"customcol1":"4datacolumn1","customcol2":"4datacolumn2","customcol3":"4datacolumn3","customcol4":"4datacolumn4","customcol5":"4datacolumn5",}
```

**NOTE**: I didn't care to remove the final comma after the last key:value pair in each row. If you want that then you have to store all the key value pairs in a variable and `RTRIM` the comma out.

Comment: Is it somehow possible to get a sub-object with apex_json? So with some kind of apex_json.get_object or so?